# Suppress `bidi`'s logo when using `polyglossia`

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, bidi

Using the latest version of `bidi` (32.4), a logo is added to the first page's footer, reading **Typeset by the *bidi* package**.

This is obviously undesirable when composing a document meant to be viewed by others, whether a letter to one's coworkers or an exam form for one's students.

However, suppressing the logo proved challenging, and Google is (currently) no help.

This is what I currently know:

- There's a new option in `bidi` for generating a logo. From `bidi.sty`:

  ```
  \newcommand*{\@bidi@inslogo@}{\insert\@bidi@copyins@{\@bidi@logo@}}
  \newcommand*{\@bidi@logo@hb@xt@}{%
    \if@RTLmain
      \hboxR to
    \else
      \hboxL to
    \fi
  }
  \newcommand*{\@bidi@logo@}{\@bidi@logo@hb@xt@\textwidth{\hss\LRE{\bfseries Typeset by the \textsf{bidi} package}}}
  ```
- If one calls `bidi` directly, I suspect (but I'm really not sure) that setting `\usepackage[logo=off]{bidi}` might be enough to suppress that message. However, if using `polyglossia`, one cannot set the flag either way.
- It's possible to suppress the logo by adding the following to the preamble, after `\usepackage{polyglossia}`:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \let\@bidi@logo@\@empty \let\@bidi@inslogo@\@empty
  \makeatother
  ```

Why was this logo added to `bidi`? Is there a 'correct' way to suppress it?

Comment: it uses `\insert` really? in latex, that's odd.. (the redefinition looks safe enough)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using TexLive 2017 on Ubuntu Xenial, and have recently updated all packages (ugh, I never learn). This is verbatim from my `bidi.sty`.

Comment: Have you tried `\PassOptionsToPackage{logo=off}{bidi}`?

Comment: @Skillmon I didn't know about `\PassOptionsToPackage`. You're correct that specifying that before `\usepackage{polyglossia}` solves the issue as well.

Comment: @JonathanY. yes I see the same, the question wasn't really to you, more to the internet in general:-)

Comment: Can't you just load `bidi` explicitly after loading `polyglossia` with the `logo=off` option?

Comment: @AlanMunn You cannot; `bidi` must be loaded last, so you can't load it before `polyglossia`. On the other hand, calling it after fails with `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package bidi.` This is what I was saying in the 2nd bullet.

Comment: As to the “why” you should ask the author of `bidi`.

Comment: Yeah. "Why" was my way of saying I think it has no place in an open-source typesetting engine. Surely when undocumented, without returning a comment on proper suppression.

Comment: @Skillmon if you compose an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Not quite. Load `polyglossia`, then load `bidi` *then* add the `polyglossia` commands that set the language. This prevents the option clash.

Comment: @JonathanY. as to "why", see https://github.com/tex-xet/bidi/issues/60.

Comment: As to the “why” in that link, I'd like to point out I've never ever copied a single line of `bidi`.  I'm basing my work on `rlbabel` (by Braams and Lavva), which has been part of `babel` for 20 years. I considered the possibilty of basing my work on `bidi` (crediting its author, of course, as I usually do), but for several reasons I finally discarded the idea -- one of them is I'm too lazy to read the `bidi` code. But IMHO, even if I had copied anything, there is no reason to penalize `bidi` users.

Comment: I think that the `bidi` statement is much too modest. It should be something along the lines "Typeset by bidi developed by Vafa Khalighi for over 12 years without any funding or donations." In fact I think that every class/package used in an (All)TeX document should typeset something similar about itself, creators and timescale on the first page of every document; some of these, like TeX and LaTeX have been developed for many more than 12 years.

Comment: @PeterWilson, just imagine if every class and package added something like this by default. Or if the engines themselves added that. What a mess. It's not unexpected to have this feature; what's unexpected is an undocumented _default_ feature that _adds something to your text_ without prior notice in an _open-source typesetting engine_ , _and_ the author's sarcastic attitude. By the way, it's not even a logo (although bidi's logo it good). It's just a colophon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you load `bidi`  *after* loading `polyglossia` but *before* using any `polyglossia` commands that would load it as well (essentially any language setting commands), you can pass the `logo=off` option to `bidi`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[logo=off]{bidi}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}


\begin{document}

\begin{english}
Hello
\end{english}
\begin{hebrew}
שלום
\end{hebrew}
\end{document}
```

### Which approach is preferred?

As you mention in the comments, passing the option to `bidi` explicitly either via the method here or using `\PassOptionsToPackage` will fail with earlier versions of the package, whereas redefining `\@bidi@inslogo@` will not.  So if you have documents that might be compiled on different machines/distributions, the redefinition approach is clearly better.

As for using `\PassOptionsToPackage` vs. loading `bidi` immediately after `polyglossia`, the difference is probably just one of taste. Since the `\PassOptionsToPackage` can be anywhere in the loading order prior to loading `polyglossia`, it's slightly simpler to use that method.

Comment: Thank you. Since the question also touches on the 'correct' way of performing this suppression, would you mind elaborating on (why) is this more/less robust than the approach using `\PassOptionsToPackage` or the redefinition? One thing I can already observe is that both of the first two options throw an error when `bidi` doesn't recognize the option `logo` (such as with old--and perhaps future--versions), while the redefinition doesn't. On the other hand, it would fail if the maintainer changed how the logo is generated...

Comment: Another possibility, if explicitly loading `bidi` is inconvenient, is to type `\makeatletter\let\@bidi@inslogo@\@empty\makeatother` just before `\begin{document}`. But probably `\PassOptionsToPackage{logo=off}{bidi}` before loading `polyglossia` is better.

Comment: You may also want to set `pdfinfo=off` to avoid `bidi` clobbering the pdf's metadata (creator and producer).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the macro `\PassOptionsToPackage{<options>}{<package>}` to pass options to a package which is loaded inside another package or a class. It is important to do so before the package is loaded.

With this you can use `\PassOptionsToPackage{logo=off}{bidi}` prior to `\usepackage{polyglossia}` which should solve the issue.